# Using Dynamic SQL to concatenate two columns into a table header with their respective values

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a two tables, GuestList and CustomerList. I joined them and used dynamic SQL pivot table to convert the 'city' column from GuestList table into rows or table headers and the average population would be displayed under each city. So after executing the query at the bottom, my table header looks like this and the average population is displayed under each city.

---

**Time| Atlanta| Los Angeles | New York | Denver| Minneapolis**

---

But I want my table header to look like this. Basically 'Id' has four values, 1, 2,3,4 and each city has all these four ID's. I could not add all the cities but rest of the cities will also be like this.

---

**Time| Atlanta_1|| Atlanta_2|| Atlanta_3|| Atlanta_4|**

---

Could someone help me on this by writing the rest of the query on how to concatenate the two columns in the GuestList table and put their respective population underneath it.

```
declare @ColumnNames nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @ColumnNames += QUOTENAME(a.address) + ','
from GuestList as a
inner join CustomerList as b
on a.Id = b.Id
group by a.address
order by a.address 

set @ColumnNames = left(@ColumnNames, LEN(@ColumnNames)-1  )

set @SQL= N'
select Time,' + @ColumnNames + '
from 
(
select a.Time, a.city, a.population, b.Gender
from GuestList as a
inner join CustomerList as b
on a.Id = b.Id
inner join Split(@city, '','') as c
on a.city = c.Data
where a.city = c.Data
) as SourceTable
pivot
(avg(population) 
for city 
in (' 
    + @ColumnNames + 
    ')) as PivotTable
order by Time'


execute sp_executesql @SQL,
                        N'@city nvarchar(max)'
                        ,@city = 'Atlanta,Los Angeles,New York'
```

Comment: Can you post sample data and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

"FOR XML PATH" to the rescue.  Here's the basic idea...

```
CREATE TABLE #ids(id NVARCHAR(20));
INSERT #ids VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4');

CREATE TABLE #cities(city NVARCHAR(20));
INSERT #cities VALUES ('Atlanta'), ('Los Angeles'), ('New York'), ('Denver'), ('Minneapolis');

SELECT  'Time' + (
            SELECT  '|' + city + '_' + id
            FROM    #cities
            CROSS JOIN #ids
            ORDER BY city, id
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) ;
```

... yields the result ...

```
Time|Atlanta_1|Atlanta_2|Atlanta_3|Atlanta_4|Denver_1|Denver_2|Denver_3|Denver_4|Los Angeles_1|Los Angeles_2|Los Angeles_3|Los Angeles_4|Minneapolis_1|Minneapolis_2|Minneapolis_3|Minneapolis_4|New York_1|New York_2|New York_3|New York_4
```